# Not able to put server online

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf

I have my IP Address of 192.168.1.119 and I want to put my server online so other (sharing same LAN) can access it I have tried to change few configs and it didn't work, I have changed my port from 80 t0 8080 as I have IIS running on port 80. [Here](http://pastebin.com/fYeTHxPE) is my apache config(httpd.conf) file details.

I am not getting what is wrong with my config files or is there something missing that I need to setup?

**Note:** I have selected "Put Online" option from WAMP Server context menu.

http://192.168.1.119:8080/index.php

Comment: Disable windows firewall?

Comment: Yes.. it was enabled. after disabled it, able to accessing URL. Thanks a lot. Dusan.

Comment: Dont siable the firewall completely. Just allow access through port 8080

Answer (score -1):

You can access this on your local network. If you want to access your content from web then you need to check your ip address then hit the same in browser with correct port number. https://www.whatismyip.com/ for public ip address.

Comment: localhost:8080 is running on ur machine?

Comment: yes working on my machine. http://localhost:8080/index.php  is working on my machine.